# How to segue to view controller without the tab bar disappearing from the main view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

[image]

I need to segue to another `UIViewController` from my TabBarController without the tab bar disappearing from the bottom of the view.

As you can see in the picture, I want to segue to the colored view when pressing the red button from tab bar controller with the tab bar still displayed at the bottom of the view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVww0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set each of your tab roots to be a `UINativagationController`. Then set the current `UIViewControllers` as the roots of the navs. Then you can segue as much as you want and the tabbar will remain on the bottom.

e.g.

[image]

like the bottom flow, you can add another `UIViewControllers` to the right again.

Comment: my button actually is on the tab bar not in one of the view controllers, i edited the picture

Comment: @basmamahmoud your update doesn't change anything. If you want to keep the bottom bar, the root of you tab MUST be a navigationController. This allows you to have a navigation stack, inside that tab. If that button can be tapped at any time, you may need to have all of your tabs be navigationControllers, but its still the same solution

Comment: @basmamahmoud has this answered your question? If so mark the answer as accepted and close off the question so others facing the same issue know what solved your issue

Comment: thanx for your reply, actually i didn't get joy but i solved it in another way which i don't think it is professional
i started to place this button on the tab bar controller and on each view in the tab bar controller

Comment: @basmamahmoud if it unblocks you for now, great. But no long term thats a bad idea. You said you had no joy, but didn't give any details. Did you add the navigation controller as the root of the tab? What went wrong / didn't work?